# How can I fit a linear regression to 3d points in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, scatter

So I have a bunch of  points with x,y,z coordinates. I can nicely plot them with "gdl"'s or "car"'s scatterplot3d() or catter3d(). But how can I fit a linear model to these points?

Sorry, I tried a lot but can only 2d examples...

This is my data:

```
slx = c(696630.6, 696631.1, 696631.5, 696631.9)
sly = c(211185.6, 211185.2, 211185.0, 211184.9)
slz = c(1123.324, 1123.419, 1123.483, 1123.571)
```

this is how I plot

```
library(car)
scatter3d(slx, sly, slz, axis.scales=FALSE)
```

Comment: Please consider reading up on [ask] and how to produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Well, I don't think that matters for the answer, but ok...

Comment: just use `lm(y~x+z)` for example

Comment: Thanks alot. That was so(!) useful.